# android browser (webkit) select-multiple's items disappear when selected

Tags: html, css, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-browser, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have an issue with Android's webkit browser

**Items in select-multiple disappear when they are selected**

I couldn't find any solution on the web, neither nobody talking about this issue

I made the screenshots in my desktop OS just to demonstrate what's happening:

[image]

This is how it should appear:

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: sadly no :( i will try again soon though... i didn't test -webkit-appearance:none... maybe it's the way

Comment: also that failed, i also tried to change selected color with ::-webkit-selection with no luck

Comment: This is very odd... again I will see if i have time to help you out since I might deal with a form in the near future for a responsive site.

Answer (score 2):

Try by removing the "border:solid 1px black"

Comment: correction, it did work, but not the expected result. select works but looks like a select-one. it's just incredible they didn't test <select> (html 2) before putting the os on the market

Answer (score 2):

A fiddle would be nice.....I made one of my own (default i do for mobile).

I can't replicate your issue... I tested on both HTC X - One and Galaxy Note 3 using the default browser (I sued Chrome too) and no issue....Also you might want to add a selected target function like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#yourid').change(function(e) {
        var selected = $(e.target).val();
        console.dir(selected);
    }); 
});
```

This makes thing neater for modal base.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/2mSUS/286/)

Comment: you did 280+ tests?? you deserve the bounty only for this reason xD anyway must be system dependent. problem is that happens on 3 androids i have, if i don't add "border" the select is displayed as a select-one box. does this happen also to you?

Comment: ha well @Wes I have Browserstack which I can test on many..I used your css with border...no issue..could be because of my selected function

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference from the [android issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=16922) that addresses a similar issue

> when we select any option from a SELECT tag having the attribute MULTIPLE, the choosen option becomes invisible

Seems like the select multiple doesn't support css.